# How to update svn code to one revision beyond the known revision, when revision numbers are non-contiguous?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

To update the svn code to a particular revision, we can use
**svn update -r REV**

When a revision number of a file is non-contiguous, say 1, 5, 7, 10 and if we know only the revision number 7, how to reach the revision present before 7?
In this case it is 5.

Comment: Revisions of a repository are always contiguous.

Comment: However, revisions of files/folders within the repository are not, thus I provided a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that you are trying to automate writing `svn update -r5`.

One suggestion would be to parse the answer of svn log. For instance, using batch:

```
#!/bin/bash
svn up n_plus_1 target
rev=( $(svn log -l 2 target | awk '/^r[0-9]+/ {sub(/r/,"",$1); print $1}') )
svn up -r ${rev[1]} target
```

where

- target can be a file or a folder
- n_plus_1 is the revision from which you start (7 in your example)